# dell poweredge pcie training error, what to do?

Tags: hardware, dell-poweredge, bios, pci-express, pci

After telling the server to reboot, it is now displaying an “PCle training error: Internal Storage Slot” Then the next line was “System Halted!”.  It will not boot.

Recently a failed scsi hot swap drive was replaced, but it rebuilt fine and has been running fine for a week.

Any ideas?

Comment: Run a hardware scan and call Dell

Comment: I have the same problem, but going into setup (pressing F2) at boot and just exiting setup lets the server start up. This suddenly started after years of running, no HW changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We managed to get it booted by turning it off, opening it up and checking the riser/pci, etc. card connections and re-seating them.

We had also tried several power downs, restarts, and removing the newer drive.

Comment: Any reason why you did not call Dell?

Comment: Not in warranty, I was told they will not talk to us if not in warranty?

Comment: That`s a reason, indeed. Perhaps you could mention that next time.

Comment: I would add to this that Dell had me TOTALLY take the RAID card out of the box, restart it without the card, shut down again, and put the RAID card back in. This apparently /really/ reseats the card as opposed to just pushing down on it to make sure it's "in". It worked for me on a Dell R420.

Answer (score 8):

Having the same “PCle training error: Internal Storage Slot”.  I replaced one of the two capacitors on the PCIe RAID controller that was showing signs of breakdown (expanded housing). 1500uf @ 6.3V. The system now boots and has been running for more than 24 horus.

Comment: Having the same problem and after opening the server I saw the 2 capacitors were very "expanded". I will try to replace them

Answer (score 1):

dell poweredge servers are configured with only PCIe Gen 3. if your card is Gen2 or Gen1, then you will face training error.

check with your PCIe configuration. If it is FPGA Configured PCIe then check the configurations and bit file which should be strictly Gen3 only.

we too faced that issue and finally my friend find it.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem on a number of Dell 11G (R610) and 12G (R620/R720) systems.  While I can't be sure what the problem is, it just seems to boil down to a hardware compatibility problem.

In my case, the system will usually boot fine the first time when powering up, but a warm reboot without cycling the power will lead to the error.  For a while I was just ensuring the servers were power cycled rather than just restarted, but ultimately it will require some kind of replacement to fix.

One of the errors I received was caused by installing a USB3.0 PCIe card.  Moving it to a different slot did not help, but replacing it with a USB3.0 card that used a different chipset solved the problem.  In another case, installing an Intel X520 10GbE card from a Dell R610 into an R620 caused the problem, but replacing the Intel card with one from Silicon Image (that used a different Intel chipset) fixed the problem.  This is quite surprising as the Dell firmware supports the Intel X520 (and the R620 lifecycle manager even did a firmware update of it for me) yet it still resulted in the PCIe training error.

Ultimately it just seems to come down to this - if you get the PCIe training error, replace the card in question with a different model.