# Dell Poweredge R620 PCIe Training error what to do?

Tags: pci-express

After the startup, the server show the "`PCIe Training error :Integrated RAID`"

And then "`PCIe express error interrupt at F000:B891`"

My thought is that the controller raid is broken

Any help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried referring to any of these ideas: https://serverfault.com/questions/310041/dell-poweredge-pcie-training-error-what-to-do

Answer (score 2):

This mainly occurs due to a faulty PCIe slot, just remove anything that is connected to the slot no, or change the entire card if possible

Answer (score 1):

Remove power cables and press power button for 10 sec and wait for 5 to 10 min, then start the server, it will work most of the times.
if not
you need to reconnect PCI cards and try. if there is any H/W issue contact hardware vendor.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I had the same issue on a Dell R520.

Reseating the cards did not help -> I replaced the Perc H710 Mini RAID Controller with a new one - error fixed.